# 405 (Method Not Allowed) - Next.js 13 Stripe Payment

Tags: reactjs, next.js, stripe-payments

I am trying to integrate Stripe payment gateway into my Next.js application. I have followed their documentation but I am not getting an headway.

How can I resolve the follwoing error:

> 405 (Method Not Allowed)

*CheckForm.js*

```
// components/CheckoutForm.js
import { CardElement, useStripe, useElements } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
import axios from 'axios';

const CheckoutForm = ({ cartItems, email }) => {
  const stripe = useStripe();
  const elements = useElements();

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  
    if (!stripe || !elements) {
      return;
    }
  
    try {
      const response = await fetch("/api/checkout_sessions", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          items: cartItems
        }),
      });
  
      const data = await response.json();
  
      // Destructure clientSecret directly from the response
      const { clientSecret } = data;
  
      // Confirm the card payment
      const result = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
        payment_method: {
          card: elements.getElement(CardElement),
          billing_details: {
            email: email,
          },
        },
      });
  
      if (result.error) {
        // Show error to your customer
        console.error(result.error.message);
      } else if (result.paymentIntent.status === "succeeded") {
        // Payment succeeded, you can redirect or show a success message
        console.log("Payment succeeded!");
        // Redirect or show success message
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error:", error.message);
    }
  };
  

  return (
    <div className="bg-gray-200 pt-3 pb-2" >
        <small className="flex w-full justify-left">Credit / Debit Card Details</small>
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    
    <div style={{ margin: '20px 0' }}>
      <CardElement />
    </div>
    <button className="mt-8 flex w-full justify-center rounded-md border border-transparent bg-[#f1592a] py-2 px-4 text-sm font-medium text-white shadow-sm" type="submit" disabled={!stripe}>
      Pay
    </button>
  </form>
  </div>
  );
};

export default CheckoutForm;
```

**app/api/check_sessions/route.js**

```
const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  switch (req.method) {
    case "POST":
      try {

        const { items } = req.body;

        // Create an array to store line items
        const lineItems = items.map((item) => ({
            price: item.priceId, // Replace with the actual Price ID from your data
            quantity: item.quantity,
        }));


        // Create Checkout Sessions from body params.
        const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
          ui_mode: 'embedded',
          line_items: lineItems,
          mode: 'payment',
          return_url: `${req.headers.origin}/return?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
        });

        res.send({clientSecret: session.client_secret});
      } catch (err) {
        res.status(err.statusCode || 500).json(err.message);
      }
    case "GET":
      try {
        const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(req.query.session_id);

        res.send({
          status: session.status,
          customer_email: session.customer_details.email
        });
      } catch (err) {
        res.status(err.statusCode || 500).json(err.message);
      }
    default:
      res.setHeader('Allow', req.method);
      res.status(405).end('Method Not Allowed');
  }
}
```

Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong. I have tried all kind of methods to resolve this issue but none of them works.

Comment: is this nextjs 13?

Comment: @Matt, Yes it is.

Comment: Maybe add some logs so you can print out exactly what value `req.method` (or even just `req` itself) is in the backend code for your `handler` function, since that seems to be where the problem is manifesting.

Answer (score 0):

Your route file is setup incorrectly.

Nextjs changed the way routes are handled in next 13.

For defining specific request its done like this

```
export async function GET(request) {...
```

Then for returning a response it's like

```
return NextResponse.json({ name:'John Doe' }, {status: 200})
```

So to put it all together your route file would be

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

export async function GET(request) {
   try {
       const session_id = request.nextUrl.searchParams.get("session_id")
       const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(session_id);

    return NextResponse.json({ 
        status: session.status,
        customer_email: session.customer_details.email
     }, {status: 200})
  } catch (err) {
    return NextResponse.json(err.message, {status: err.statusCode || 500})
  }
}

export async function GET(request) {
try {
    const body = request.json()
    const { items } = body;

    // Create an array to store line items
    const lineItems = items.map((item) => ({
        price: item.priceId, // Replace with the actual Price ID from your data
        quantity: item.quantity,
    }));


    // Create Checkout Sessions from body params.
    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
      ui_mode: 'embedded',
      line_items: lineItems,
      mode: 'payment',
      return_url: `${req.headers.origin}/return?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
    });

    return NextResponse.json({clientSecret: session.client_secret}, {status: 200})
} catch (err) {
    return NextResponse.json(err.message, {status: err.statusCode || 500})
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to help. I will try it.